# AMD FX-8350 confusion on heating

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, amd-cpu

My AMD FX-8350, from what I understand, is overheating. The issue is, when I research it, I get conflicting results. It's idling at around 52c-58c, I was able to get it to 48c with the side open and a fan pointed at the opening. From stuff a bit more focused on the FX 8350, they say that the 50c-60c are too high and it should be 30cs-40cs. But other places and people I know irl are saying that 50c-60c is normal for a CPU to be at. I'm not under load, I'm just running BIOS.

I've redone the thermal paste, and have 2 fans, intake in the back and exhaust in the bottom. I know that's stupid but that's the only setup I can have unless flipping the fans around would be better. Actually as I type this, I realize heat rises so it's probably better but that probably wont be enough to bring it down to the 40s. I have no logical reasoning why it would be running that hot.

for parts, FX 8350, GTX 1060 3gb, Asrock 970g-a/3.1, 16 GB DDR3. the GPU and MOBO are fine on heat it's only the CPU

So, what's the right numbers? Is 50c-60c a fine number or should I be concerned? Would flipping the fans around be a better alternative? Is the MOBO's BIOS known for bad readings on the temps? I want to try everything I can before spending more money.

Comment: That fan arrangement is suboptimal. Can the fan actually draw/push out air through the bottom of the case or is it obstructed? You also have a graphics card in the way. On the other hand: is the CPU actually thermal throttling?

Comment: 50-60c is OK. Don't worry.

Comment: @gronostaj The case has stands so there’s enough of a gap for them to find air. In terms of thermal throttling, before putting in a second fan and re-doing paste, the CPU would reach 80c and then shut off, so I worry how it performs under load

Comment: FX-8350 has max temp of 61°C [(click)](https://superuser.com/q/1154402/194694) so it's already thermal throttling when idle and shuts off at 80+ to prevent damage. The stands are probably too low to provide sufficient airflow. Can you post a photo of the computer with side panel removed? Use the [Edit] button.